# How could I pass the parent instance reference to the child element in the ui.xml?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I want to pass the parent reference to the child element in the ui.xml.

Here is the Child.java

```
public class Child extends Composite {

    private static ChildUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(ChildUiBinder.class);
    
    ParentView parentView;
    
    interface ChildUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Child> {
    }
    
    public  Child( ) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        
    }

    public ParentView getParentView() {
        return parentView;
    }

    public void setParentView(ParentView parentView) {
        this.parentView = parentView;
    }

}
```

And here is UI definition in the parent.ui.xml

```
...
<g:HTMLPanel>


   <my:Child ui:field='child' mainView= "{this}"/>

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Obviously, this way to pass parent reference is not correct.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @DarkScrolls, I want to pass the parent ui reference into child ui, not in child.java file, but in child.ui.xml

Comment: What feature are you trying to develop? What do you want to display in the parent or child widgets? What do you want from this reference? Probably you would achieve what you want in another way. A specific question would help you getting the answer you need.